# Which technique is best suited for chat-like app

Tags: node.js, mobile, xmpp

I want to develop a mobile app where a registered user can search among other registred users. User A can chat with user B. User A can view user B's profile. Upon this, user B have to be informed that user A is watching him.
So its some kind of chatroom where the server should be able to be notified when a user watched/contact another user, and let the latter know about this.
My first idea was to use node.js. But I begun to read a lot on XMPP-protocol. Do you think an XMPP-server would be more adequate to this kind of app? What I udnerstand you can customize your xmpp-server, write plugins so it can behave the way you want. Is this correct?

Comment: XMPP might be a bit heavy weight for a simple one-to-one chat. The [Faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/node.html) pub/sub library is probably easier to use and supports private channels, auto-reconnect and websockets, long polling, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect use case for socket IO using NodeJS. In fact, I have implemented exactly what you are describing with an iOS client and node backend in less than 50 lines of code. See https://github.com/MegaBits/SIOSocket for the iOS library, and http://socket.io/ for SocketIO.

XMPP is much heavier and verbose, and you'll be spending a lot of time parsing/building XML when you could just be communicating in JSON all the way. Take a look at my repo here:

https://github.com/alhill10/chatapp3/blob/master/View%20Control%20App/ChatView.m#L34

You can see on the `viewDidLoad` method it simply opens a websocket connection and listens for events from the server, then updates the tableview being used as a chat window with any new incoming messages in real time.

Then, look here https://github.com/alhill10/simplechat/blob/master/app.js for a simple example of the Socket IO backend that receives and relays the messages, as well as maintaining the state of current users online. You could trivially add in user authentication and .